# How to block a user to some hours

Tags: android

In my app, case the user contravenes some of our laws, the his account will be blocked for some hours and will cannot use the app.
How to program this? The question of scheduling and next hours unlock it again?

Comment: I noticed none of your questions have accepted answers. If an answer helps, make sure to press the checkmark to indicate so.

Comment: Ok, sorry @RuchirBaronia

Comment: Thats fine! :) did my answer help you in this question?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Hashmap that maps the user id with the time when he's banned somewhere on the server or the app, then check the time elapsed when changing fragments, when the time is over, remove that item, otherwise jump to the banned screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if(doesBad){
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, true);
        editor.commit();

     new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("Yay, not banned anymore!");
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, false);
        editor.commit();
     }  
    }.start();

        }
```

**AND IN ON CREATE FOR EVERY ACTIVITY:**

```
if(!prefs.getBoolean(PREF_NAME, false)){
setContentView(R.layout.youarebanned);
}
```

Comment: I read about the AlarmMananger, I dont know if the CountDownTimer is good for long times..

Comment: @MateusCarvalho How long is your "banned" time?

Comment: @MateusCarvalho I don't think there is any problem with having CountDownTimer for long times...

Comment: But, if the close the app, countdowntimer was continued running?

Comment: @MateusCarvalho Yes, put it in a service then